# What function f() should be called to produce something different?

Tags: c

Consider the following code:

```
void f(int *p1, int *p2) {
     *p1 = 5;
     *p2 = 6;
     printf("%d %d\n", *p1, *p2);
}
```

I have a question that asks how to call f() to print something other than a line containing 5 6. The best I have tried so far is to make f() prints "Segmentation fault", but I do not think it is an appropriate answer for this problem. Any hint would be really appreciated!

Comment: `f(&x, &x)`, the first assignment of `5` will be pointless.

Comment: `char buf[10]; f(&buf[0], &buf[1]);` could lead to buf fault or something interesting.

Answer (score 7):

Consider what will happen if you pass the same address in `p1` and `p2`.

Answer (score 4):

This would print "6 6" instead of "5 6"

```
int n = 1;
f(&n, &n);
```

Comment: Brilliant! You're awesome! Just realised how silly I am do not think of that :))

Answer (score -2):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void f(int *p1, int *p2) {
     *p1 = 5;
     *p2 = 6;
     printf("%d %d\n", *p1, *p2);
}

int main()
{
    int data1 = 1, data2 = 2;
    f(&data1, &data2);
    return 0;
}
```

that's it. f() function requires two pointers as its parameters.

Comment: `data1` and `data2` get set to 5 and 6 by `f()`. Setting them to 1 and 2 before calling won't change that.